# Is it possible to return rows along with the number of rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have this query

```
SELECT T1.Col1,
       (
         SELECT TOP 1 T3.Col1
         FROM Table3 T3
         INNER JOIN Table4 T4
         ON T3.Col3 = T4.Col1
         WHERE T4.Col2 = T1.Col1
       )
       T1.Col2,
       T1.Col3,
       T2.Col1
       T2.Col2
       FROM Table1 T1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
       ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col2
```

So far, `SELECT TOP 1` returns one row. Is there a way to return the count as well? I'd like to returns something like `AA_123_BB_4567 (3).` Where 3 is the number of columns, since I can only display the first row.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you provide little detail on what your tables look like and what your expected result would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question properly, you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT T1.Col1,
       (
         SELECT TOP 1 T3.Col1
         FROM Table3 T3
         INNER JOIN Table4 T4
         ON T3.Col3 = T4.Col1
         WHERE T4.Col2 = T1.Col1
       ) as the_top_1,
       (
         SELECT count(1)
         FROM Table3 T3
         INNER JOIN Table4 T4
         ON T3.Col3 = T4.Col1
         WHERE T4.Col2 = T1.Col1
       ) as the_count,
       T1.Col2,
       T1.Col3,
       T2.Col1
       T2.Col2
       FROM Table1 T1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
       ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col2
```

or this:

```
SELECT 
    T1.Col1,
    T1.Col2,
    T1.Col3,
    T2.Col1,
    T2.Col2,
    x.top_1,
    x.the_count
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col2 
left join (
    SELECT
        T4.col2,
        min(T3.Col1) as top_1,
        COUNT(1) as the_count
    FROM Table3 T3
    INNER JOIN Table4 T4 ON T3.Col3 = T4.Col1
    group by T4.col2
) x on x.Col2 = T1.Col1
```

Comment: Exactly, but I was hoping that there is a way to write them in one statement.

Comment: @Richard77 - I updated my answer with another approach